# Can I program AVR Microcontrollers using Arduino Development board with Atmel Studio?

Tags: arduino, avr, atmelstudio

I know and I can program any AVR microcontroller with Arduino IDE and Arduino Uno board. Can I use Arduino board with AVR Studio? Or I have to buy an AVR Development board?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a guide,how to program with Atmel Studio 6
http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/#flash

Here is a video tutorial to burn the bootloader on Arduino Uno with Atmel Studio
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2C5apH2mhc

Answer (score 0):

You should try the Visual Micro plugin with Atmel studio 6.2. http://www.visualmicro.com/